# No module named AWSLex found after installing cocoa pod for swift iOS app

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate Amazon Lex service into my app, however after successfully installing cocoa pod , I can't import it in my `appdelegate.swift` file. Every other cocoapod is getting imported except all the AWS ones.
Am I using the correct cocoapod?

```
pod 'AWSLex'
pod 'AWSCognitoAuth'
pod 'AWSCore'
```

Comment: Clean Clean and Clean. exit Xcode and restart, maybe restart your computer. That mostly will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I did try that. Still the problem is not resolved. Same issue was there with API.ai , however when I used differe

Answer (score 0):

I used pod AWSS3 as well. And it resolved the issue. I suppose they have some dependencies. Thanks.